# Python List Doesn't Update

Tags: python, list, loops, integer

I am trying to solve a seemingly simple problem on Python. I am trying to update the last 3 element of a list to other integers. Here is the code:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in xrange(len(list[2:])):
    list[2:][i] = 44444

print list
```

But when I print the list, it still remains the same. I observe the changes in debugger and I found that the list doesn't update in the loop. I tried searching elsewhere on Google and Stack Overflow, but none of them provide answers to this simple problem.

Let me know what you guys think about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A slice of a list is a new list; it doesn’t reference the original or anything like that. Assign to `list[2 + i]` instead. (You can avoid making an extra slice to get the length in the same way.)

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in xrange(len(list) - 2):
    list[2 + i] = 44444

print list
```

Answer (score 0):

A slice creates a new list, unless you assign to it:

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> values[-3:] = [4444] * 3
>>> values
[0, 1, 4444, 4444, 4444]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `for i in xrange(len(list[2:])):` you are reducing the length of list from 5 to 3. Your loop would iterate only for the first 3 list items.
Instead you could do something like this:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(3,len(a)):
   a[i]=444
print(a)
```